# Is it possible to do a chi squared test on pairwise data with repetitions?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, paired-data

I'd like to reproduce an article's analysis, but I'm having trouble understanding how a chi squared test is appropriate for their data.

The experiment is within-subject. There are 2 conditions, and each of the 60 subjects ran each condition 3 times. The data looks like this:

```
subject, condition, response
s1, A, 20
s1, A, 30
s1, A, 28
s1, B, 41
s1, B, 32
s1, B, 36
s2, A, 27
s2, A, 35
s2, A, 36
s2, B, 31
s2, B, 30
s2, B, 33
s3, etc...
```

The paper reports that people respond with a higher value for B compared with A and reports a chi squared statistic with 1 df. No information is given on what kind of chi squared (McNemar?).

- How would I perform a chi squared test on this type of data?
- Should I collapse each subject*condition to a single observation by taking the mean of `response` for each subject*condition?
- How do I indicate that it's pairwise data?

I've tried the `mcnemar.test()` function in R, but I can't figure out what format it wants the data in.

*I'd usually run an ANOVA `anova(lm(response ~ condition + subject, data))` as long as it was close to normal. I'm not familiar with running chi squared outside of simple 2x2 matrices, so help would be appreciated!*

Comment: are the data counts or some other type of variable?

Comment: The data are of counts... sort of. To keep it simple, imagine the task is that 500 balls are thrown in the air. The subject has a net that they can place on the ground beforehand. The value is the number of balls that land in the net.

Comment: In that case it seems like they made use of a 60 subjects times 2 conditions contingency table with means from the three values per subject and condition. Testing independence of results a and b would lead to a chi-square test with 1 degree of freedom. The interesting part of independence means that the mean of a and b do not need to differ for the test to be negative. So it is *not* a good test for the hypothesis that the means of a and b differ. Maybe they summed all values a and b resulting in two values, and also a chi-square test of degree 1.

Comment: Was the chi-squared statistic high (model used to calculate chi false) or low (model not false)?

Comment: Thanks @MartijnWeterings. The statistic was `x^2(1) = 11`.

Comment: So then they calculated chi-square according to some kind of model, and because chi is high concluded that the model is false. The only model falsification that would lead to the alternative model that b>a would be when they summed all a and b values (2x1 table as result) and assume a=b. If they did a chi-square test on the difference a-b individually (such as a 60x2 or 60x1 table) and model that these should be 0, then an alternative model would also be, for instance, when half the people have very low negative and and half the people very high positive contrast values a-b.

Comment: This (2x1) model would be a low power test, because the variation of individuals is not filtered out (as done in pairwise comparisons). Other models would wrongly apply the concept of the chi-square test.

Comment: Yeah, agreed. Their stat is pretty high. When I've tried the 2x1 approach, I get a garbage result (x^2=0.6). So I assume something's up with their analysis.